# Can't analyzeload test results in visual studio 2013

Tags: testing, visual-studio-2013

what does that count field(that is with Avg. page time filed) in the load test result in page results section represents and what is its relation with Avg Page time .. I can't understand that what does that count shows as every time i run the test it shows the different count figures so what exactly this count is representing here?? i am using visual studio 2013 ultimate
I am new to load testing so any help would be appreciated 
Thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The count is the number of times that page was requested - by any user - during the test.

Your test will have requested a particular page many times. The response time for each request for that page is saved in the test result set. How would you tell someone what the response time for that page is?

You could provide a list of each and every response time, but this would be hard to read. This is where statistics comes in handy - it's a language for summarising large sets of data.

You can condense the long list of values to a single value by stating an average. To give a better picture of your result set you could also say how big the list of response times is by stating the count.